# Volley, ngrok - Can't make a post request using Volley to a ngrok REST api

Tags: android, kotlin, httprequest, android-volley, ngrok

I have been using ngrok for a bunch of projects, mostly voice apps and rest apis. I just needed to use my rest api in an android app. However, whatever I do, it does not work for some reasons!

If I try it with http, this is the error I get:

```java
E/Volley: [17118] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for http://1z5d90b4.ngrok.io/api/v1/users/id/
I/System.out: That didn't work! com.android.volley.ServerError
```

If I try the https link, this is what I get:

```java
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xd7821100: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

I don't know why and what is going on! I checked ngrok runnign on my computer, and it does not receive anything. FYI, I am making a post request on that url using Volley in Kotlin, this is my code:

```java
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, apiUrl, params,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    println("Response is: $response")
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->  println("That didn't work! ${error}") })
        queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Comment: The URL you're trying `http://1z5d90b4.ngrok.io/api/v1/users/id/` doesnt look correct. Could be.. but its strange there is no final URL parameter, e.g. the User ID ?

Comment: Actually I cut the url, just because I thought it's not necessary. but it is soemthing like this:
```http://1z5d90b4.ngrok.io/api/v1/users/A328dJDFj39dj34L/status
```
And it works when I make requests using Postman

Comment: Seems strange that your URL is http but the error is SSL related...?

Comment: @CodyCaughlan 
Thank you for your time for checking the code and responding. I found the problem! It was the network firewall! I just did not expect this, because at work we have a guest and a work network. My assumption was that since the work network is more secure, if something works fine on the work network, it will work on guest network as well!! However, ngrok was blocked on the guest network, and that was the only issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem! Sounds silly, but it was the **network firewall**! Once I switched the network, everything worked out!!!

Just to add something, if you had an issue with HTTP request, try to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to AndroidManifest.xml file. It will be something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>

    <!--Add this line if you haven't added it yet-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        ...

       <!--ALSO, this can fix some of the problems-->
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"


        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```